# degree of a field extension notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need some help understanding the notation for the degree of a field extension.

For example we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q})]=2$

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = a + b\sqrt{2}$ so the degree is 2.

Where I get confused is when we have something like $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$.

How do we write $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$?

Besides that I would say $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]$

so $?*2 = 6 \Leftrightarrow ?=3$

Comment: Are you asking how to compute this dimension or what the notation means? I'm not sure what you mean by "how do we write $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2}) : \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)]$." You've already written it.

Comment: I want to know how to compute it. I'm not even really sure what $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]$ means. What if I had something like $\math{R}(i):\mathbb{Q}$ (not sure if this makes sense). Basically I want to know how I use these two fields to get the dimension of the vector space. In my book the notation is defined as the dimesion of $K$ (which is some extension of a field $F$) as a vector space over $F$. I'm not sure how to get the dimension of a vector space using the definiton.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ refers to the minimal field containing both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt2$; it contains elements of the form $a + b\sqrt2$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$.  If you meant to write $[\mathbb{R}(i) : \mathbb{Q}]$, that is of infinite degree, as is $[\mathbb{R} : \mathbb{Q}]$.  ($\mathbb{R}(i)$ is just $\mathbb{C}$.)

Comment: The fact that all elements in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ are of the form $a + b\sqrt2$ *means* that the field extension is of degree $2$; they constitute a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, with a $1$-"axis" and a $\sqrt2$-"axis," so to speak.  (ETA: I see that you already wrote some of this in your question, so I'm just repeating some of this back to you, but hopefully with some helpful context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your question is about "what does an element look like," similar to how the elements of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ look like $a+b\sqrt2$ for $a, b \in \mathbb Q$. Well, we know that $\sqrt[6]{2}$ is a root of $x^6-2 \in \mathbb Q[x]$, and this is an irreducible polynomial (by [Eisenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) at 2). This means that $$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2}):\mathbb Q]= 6,$$ and so by the degree formula you were mentioning earlier, $$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2}):\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)] = 3.$$ This tells us that our extension is of degree 3, so we just need to find the three basis elements. It is rather simple to check that the basis is $$\{1, \sqrt[6]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}\},$$ and so an element of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2})$ when viewed as a field over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is simply $$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[6]{2}) = \{a + b \sqrt[6]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{2} \mid a, b, c \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt2)\}.$$ Hope that helps!